# how to alter LOCAL partitioned index?

Tags: oracle, indexing, partition

I have this script already running in the production:

```
CREATE INDEX WZAQXS1A
ON WZAQTS1(PRO_PARTITION)
local
( PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_74 tablespace wz0qdix1_74
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_76 tablespace wz0qdix1_76
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_77 tablespace wz0qdix1_77
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_78 tablespace wz0qdix1_78
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_7D tablespace wz0qdix1_7D
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_7J tablespace wz0qdix1_7J
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_81 tablespace wz0qdix1_81
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_82 tablespace wz0qdix1_82
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_85 tablespace wz0qdix1_85
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_858 tablespace wz0qdix1_858
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_859 tablespace wz0qdix1_859
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_88 tablespace wz0qdix1_88
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_89 tablespace wz0qdix1_89
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_89M tablespace wz0qdix1_89M
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_8E tablespace wz0qdix1_8E
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CA tablespace wz0qdix1_CA
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CC tablespace wz0qdix1_CC
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CH tablespace wz0qdix1_CH
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CJ tablespace wz0qdix1_CJ
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CP tablespace wz0qdix1_CP
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CS tablespace wz0qdix1_CS
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_CX tablespace wz0qdix1_CX
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_FL tablespace wz0qdix1_FL
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_FT tablespace wz0qdix1_FT
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_FV tablespace wz0qdix1_FV
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_FW tablespace wz0qdix1_FW
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_U9 tablespace wz0qdix1_U9
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_UW tablespace wz0qdix1_UW
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_UX tablespace wz0qdix1_UX
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_YN tablespace wz0qdix1_YN
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_72 tablespace WZ0QDIX1_72
, PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_KI tablespace WZ0QDIX1_KI
);
```

i want to add a new partition to it

i try using the following script

```
alter index 
   WZAQXS1A 
add partition 
   part_WZAQXS1A_KI 
tablespace 
   WZ0QDIX1_KI;
```

but it gives me this error:

> ORA-14076: submitted alter index partition/subpartition operation is not valid for local partitioned index
>   14076. 00000 -  "submitted alter index partition/subpartition operation is not valid for local partitioned index"
>   *Cause:    User attempted to either drop, split, add or coalesce a partition or
>              a subpartition of a local index which is illegal.
>   *Action:   Ensure that the index named in such statement is a global
>              partitioned index.

how to i add a new partition 'KI'?

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL?

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but the partition name in the `ALTER` statement already exists on the index. You might try choosing another partition name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a partition to a local index. Add (or split) the partition on **table**, then the index partition will be created automatically.

The new partition will be stored in default tablespace, this you can set by

```
ALTER INDEX WZAQXS1A MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES TABLESPACE WZ0QDIX1_KI;
```

Or you can afterwards move the index partition like

```
ALTER INDEX WZAQXS1A REBUILD PARTITION part_WZAQXS1A_KI TABLESPACE WZ0QDIX1_KI;
```